# bash language output

Tags: bash, locale

In my english linux system, I have

```
$ diff a b
Only in b: bmm.awda
Common subdirectories: a/c and b/c
Only in b: gsegwehh
Only in a: Link to t
Only in b: new file (4th copy)
Only in a: r
Only in a: t
Only in b: zxzxczx
```

what would be the output in a system with a different language? Are bash commands output translated to every language?? Like in Italian I would have

```
$ diff a b
Solo in b: bmm.awda
Subdirectories comuni: a/c e b/c
Solo in b: gsegwehh
Solo in a: Link to t
Solo in b: new file (4th copy)
Solo in a: r
Solo in a: t
Solo in b: zxzxczx
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `bash` quite often translates output depending on your locale settings. But this also depends on how the tools / scripts are written. There is a section about ["Locale Specific Translation"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Locale-Translation) in the BASH manual.